# DimpleJS legend limited to part of the series

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I'm using DimpleJS to render a BubblePlot. My data looks like this:

```
[
   {type: "A", name:"First", x:1, y:200}, 
   {type: "A", name:"Second", x:30, y:10}, 
   {type: "B", name:"Third", x:50, y:120}, 
   {type: "B", name:"Fifth", x:90, y:100}
]
```

The graph is created with:

```
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, chartData);
myChart.setBounds(50, 30, 370, 230);
var x = myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "x");
var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "y");
var series = myChart.addSeries(["type", "name"], dimple.plot.bubble);
myChart.addLegend(10, 10, 360, 20, "right");
myChart.draw();
```

This nearly does what I want, with all the data available in the tooltips etc. But coloring is based on both `type`and `name`.

Also unfortunately the legend also picks up all the values from the `name` field where I'd prefer to just see the `type` values within the legend.

I also tried to the use the `addColorAxis`method like this:

```
var c = myChart.addColorAxis("type");
var series = myChart.addSeries("name", dimple.plot.bubble);
```

But that renders black bubbles, shows "NaN" as `type` in the tooltips and putting that into a legend also doesn't seem to be possible.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the order of arguments in the series is important.

This solved my problem:

```
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, chartData);
myChart.setBounds(50, 30, 370, 230);
var x = myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "x");
var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "y");
var series = myChart.addSeries(["name","type"], dimple.plot.bubble);
myChart.addLegend(10, 10, 360, 20, "right");
myChart.draw();
```